# How can I turn on wifi and hotspot simultaneously in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in which I am unable to turn on the hotspot as well as wifi simultaneously.

I want to share the internet which I am using.

I have dual boot with Windows 10 in which I can use wifi and hotspot at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Install Linux wifi hotspot

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lakinduakash/lwh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-wifi-hotspot
```

Then find the wifi hotspot program in your program menu

The create_ap hasn't been maintained since July 2020

Comment: tried this but always says "not running"

Comment: What wireless device are you using?  It works fine with my Atheros wifi but it has issues with my RTL8814AU USB wifi and it works with a Mediatek MT7612U usb wifi

Comment: description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
driver=rtw_8822be 
driverversion=5.8.0-45-generic

Comment: Also getting "not running". It seemed like I was so near a solution...

Comment: @Tachytaenius try starting it in terminal and see if you get an error that may be helpful.  Some devices do not support running dual mode with linux kernel modules

Comment: This works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You will need `hostapd` package and `create_ap` utility to do this. `hostapd` (host access point daemon) is a background process that can be used to create authenticated servers and access points.

`create_ap` is actually a script that offers some useful Wireless features. One of the features is creating a **bridged Wi-Fi access point**. You can go through its features and commands  [here](https://codeload.github.com/oblique/create_ap/zip/refs/heads/master)

First, install the `hostapd` package

```
sudo apt install hostapd
sudo apt update
```

Now, download the **create_ap-master** zip file from [here](https://codeload.github.com/oblique/create_ap/zip/refs/heads/master)

Extract the zip file, open a terminal in that directory (create_ap-master) and then run the following command

```
sudo make install
```

You have installed all the necessary tools. Now, you need to find out the Wi-Fi interface name which usually starts with `wl`. To get get this, simply run

```
ifconfig
```

If the above command did not work, install the `net-tools` package and run the above command again. The `ifconfig` stands for interface configuration and it gives all the possible interfaces that your network card can establish. You can see the results starting with `en` (ethernet), `lo` (loopback) and `wl` (wifi). Note down the wifi interface name e.g., `wlo1`

You can use the example commands in the official github page of `create_ap` that is given in the first link. For creating an ap sharing the same wifi interface, the given example is[image]

Note that `wlan0` is the wifi interface name. Replace it with the wifi interface name you got from the results of `ifconfig` command. So, to creat an wifi access point with <hotspot_name> and <pass_word>, run the following command.

```
sudo create_ap wlan0 wlan0 <hotspot_name> <pass_word>
```

Don't forget to replace `wlan0` with your wifi interface name. Also, choose your desired hotspot name and password. After successfully doing the above steps, you can see your device's wifi and hotspot running simultaneously. It can now share the internet connection through an access point you just created.

Comment: all goes well but in the end i might have enabled --no-virt option and due to which i am unable to create wifi and hotspot at the same time. I am uploading the output image of the termnal.
Please help me to disable --no-virt option.
[image](https://i.ibb.co/c22n9Hq/Screenshot-from-2021-03-21-18-52-46.png)

Comment: Find out the type of wireless network card your device has by running `lspci` command. If its an intel card, you have a little bit of chancee to rectify this I think. Intel provides linux supported drivers in its website. But if it is a realtek one, there is a very slim chance. Because I have never seen any linux supported drivers for realtek network cards.

Comment: Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter

Comment: Can't state how grateful I am for this <3