# wifi to wifihotspot

Tags: wireless

Hi in windows 11 i'm easily convert my wifi to wifihotspot with just one click but in ubuntu 22.04 its not work if if create wifihot spot it's automatically turn off my wifi if i enable wifi then it's off hotspot i'm not able use simultaneously this is only reason for me to leave ubuntu other wise i'm love ubuntu please provide me this features as soon as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I turn on wifi and hotspot simultaneously in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324822/how-can-i-turn-on-wifi-and-hotspot-simultaneously-in-ubuntu-20-04)