# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi-Hotspot

Tags: 20.04, wireless, hot-spot

I have dual boot my laptop windows 11 and ubuntu 20.04. When i go to settings "Turn on wifi hotspot" is grayed out. I tried multiple times but didn't work.

1. Going in settings then 'network' then 'wifi'.
2. Reinstalling wifi driver
   Please reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I turn on wifi and hotspot simultaneously in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324822/how-can-i-turn-on-wifi-and-hotspot-simultaneously-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: if you don't want to be connected to a WiFi and providing hotspot at the same time (as @graham mentioned), see question [Turn on Wi-FI hotspot disabled in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214452/turn-on-wi-fi-hotspot-disabled-in-ubuntu-18-04) for more details (looks like similar problem you might have, maybe just some bug..)

Comment: Might want to try https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot What wifi device are you using as not all drivers allow hotspot